# U163 Error message

Tags: printer, ink, canon-pixma

I get a U163 error message, saying I have run out of black ink, but I just replaced the ink cartridge.  No what do I do?

Comment: Have you reset the printer?

Answer (score 1):

quoting http://fix-your-printer.blogspot.pt/2009/06/error-u163-on-canon-printers-mx-series.html after a **google search** :

"Press and hold the 'Reset' button down for 5 seconds."

hope it helps.